# Search between dates in SQl

Tags: sql, oracle, date-comparison

I have a date-picker in my form which generate one start date and end date while submitting a form. The date format is `'#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',` for both. From my oracle DB, i need to compare theses two inputs against column value TIMESTAMP with date format `date('Y-m-d')`. My  SQL query is

```
SELECT TITLE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2015-07-15' AND '2015-07-30' 
GROUP BY TITLE ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

Can i search like this?I didn't got any results with this query.

Answer (score 2):

> WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2015-07-15' AND '2015-07-30'

You are comparing a **DATE** with **string**. You must use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert a string into date.

For example,

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP 
BETWEEN 
   TO_DATE('2015-07-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND 
   TO_DATE('2015-07-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

When you only have the date element with fixed literal format, I prefer **ANSI date literal**

```
DATE '2015-07-15'
```

The above query could be written with less code using **ANSI date literal**:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP 
BETWEEN 
   DATE '2015-07-15'
AND 
   DATE '2015-07-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `MSSQL Query`

```
SELECT TITLE FROM TABLE WHERE  convert(varchar(50),TIMESTAMP ,111)
BETWEEN '2015-07-15' AND '2015-07-30' GROUP BY TITLE ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

Comment: There is no `convert()` in Oracle

Comment: It is for SQL as written in question

Comment: There is no `convert()` in SQL either. "*SQL*" is just a *query language*, not a specific DBMS product.